# BitcoinJ generate address from private key

Tags: java, bitcoin, bitcoinj

I'm facing an issue regarding generating `address` from `private key`.

I got the **master private key** from `electrum` as well as from `bitcoin core`
that is starts from

```
xprv9s21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in bitcoinJ:

```
ECKey key=ECKey.fromPrivate(prv); // it accepts bytes[] or BigInteger
```

how can i convert `9s21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` into `bytes[] or BigInteger`.

Try:

```
String prvkey=9s21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BigInteger bytes=new BigInteger(priv,16);
```

> it throws exception as it can't convert due to number format.

Try 2:

```
byte[] bytes=prvkey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

it generates valid address from `ECKey` and i send transaction to that `address` via `electrum`. but wallet didn't receive money. Don't know where the money gone.

what should i do to convert **master private key** into `BigInteger or bytes[]`

PS:
I'm beginner in `cryptocurrency`

Comment: `prvkey` is just a string. You can do `prvkey.getBytes()` to get its representation in bytes array

Comment: Question is: how i convert my private key that i got from electrum or bitcoin core wallet and generate valid address from it using bitcoinJ

Comment: `ECKey key=ECKey.fromPrivate(prv.getBytes());`

Comment: i hope it will work and transaction goes to actual account not a in cloud!

Comment: Do tests on the testnet. Also here's how to convert into BigInteger:  `BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(prv);`

Comment: Check out the examples from their github page:  https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/PrivateKeys.java#L58  I'll post this as an answer for future readers

Comment: i'm sending actual transaction from electrum using the address that is generated from the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert string private key into `bytes[]`:

```
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(prv.getBytes());
```

Or, convert string private key into `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(prv);
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privKey);
```

[Example from bitcoinj's github repo](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/7f5b6753f54f4dbdcb5cd411f722657c8ba6f1c6/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/PrivateKeys.java#L58)

Comment: i generated address from your methods
and send coins via electrum to that address.

Comment: after confirmation,i'll tell you whether the transactions goes to actual account which prvkey belongs or some other cloud account

Comment: Why would it go to "other cloud accounts"? If you generated the private key from one of your local wallets (core, electrum), then it should go to those address

Comment: You can accept this answer if it answered your question. Also, check out the example code I linked. That example also shows how to generate legacy addresses and make a transaction

Comment: still transaction didn't go that actual account. goes into some cloud account

Comment: You're sending some funds from addrA to addrB, right? Where did you create both addresses from? And post the tx link

Comment: lemme clear more. I've 2 electrum accounts A and B. i got the prvkey of A and got address using bitcoinJ (ECKey). now i send money from B accounts to that address which is generated from ECkey

Comment: This is out of scope of this question. Let's move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167239/discussion-between-rafid059-and-muhammad-saad).